# MySQL corrolated subquery with WHERE clause referencing outer query

Tags: mysql, sql, correlated-subquery

I want to join two tables on id columns, where the id is unique in table1, but repeats or may be absent in table2. In table2, I want to use a second column (date) to pick the greatest date which is less than the date corresponding to the date in the table1 row. I need to pick additional columns from table 2.

The query I have is:

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT `t2`.`other_column`, MAX(`t2`.`date`) FROM `t2` GROUP BY `t2`.`id` WHERE `t2`.`date`<`t1`.`date` )
ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`
```

The problem is that you can't use `t1` variables in the the WHERE clause of the the `t2` subquery.

Comment: can you post sample data and desired result including your table structure

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want with a correlated subquery in the *select* clause:

```
SELECT t1.*
       (SELECT MAX(t2.date)
        FROM t2
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.date < t1.date
       ) as t2date
FROM t1 ;
```

Comment: Your answer is spot on for the question I asked, but I'd oversimplified it for what I needed. Is its possible to select multiple columns in the subquery, rather than just one?

Comment: @Dom . . . Can you ask another question?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Misunderstood question. You will need a subquery in this case.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT id, MAX(t2.date) AS `date` FROM t2 GROUP BY id
) t3 ON (t3.id = t1.id AND t3.date < t1.date)
```

Comment: This returns one row, not one row per id.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. Let me have another look, see if it can be adapted using a similar method.

Comment: The edit doesn't answer my question. The subquery is picking out the maximum date for each id, then the ON clause is only selecting rows where the absolute maximum date for an id in t2 is less than the date in t1. What I'm after is the largest date for an in t2, which is less than the date in t1.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the subquery was a red herring and I could do it all without it.

```
SELECT `t1`.*, `t2`.*, MAX(`t2`.`date`) FROM `t1` 
LEFT JOIN `t2` 
ON (`t1`.`id`=`t2`.`id` AND `t2`.`date`<`t1`.`date`)
GROUP BY `t1`.`id`
```